# Failed opening required '/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have checked out laravel project from this svn repo. Now I get this error when I run `php artisan serve` `composer update` or `composer install` commands

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

```
  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/osmall/trunk/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /trunk/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17         
  PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/osmall/trunk/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'(include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /osmall/trunk/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

I get an additional message with the above one if I run `php composer.phar install` command

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

If i do `composer dump-autoload -o` and then run update or install commands then

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error




[RuntimeException]                                                           
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /osmall/trunk/bootstrap/app.php:14                                                                         
  Stack trace:                                                                 
  #0 /osmall/trunk/artisan(18): require_once()                
  #1 {main}                                                                    
    thrown in /osmall/trunk/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

Additional Information 
1. My composer version is 1.0.0-beta2 
2. I have both php 5.6 and 7 installed. 
3. I am running ubuntu

Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Look in your `composer.json`, and remove the `clear-compiled` command from your `pre-update-cmd` section.